# How many OS can be handle from GRUB Bootloader?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, vmware, bootloader

If you have sufficient number of partition in your hard drive or SSD, then how many OS can GRUB Bootloader run? If GRUB boots only two OS then which bootloader can be used for three or four OS?

Comment: The more you add the more cumbersome it is to use.... I've got *test* boxes that have >15 OSes listed (most are not actual installs, but ISOs that I have `grub` boot; I add them to directories & re-run a script which causes the grub to re-create & add them).  Too many and it's hard to find things..   I think ~9 is my maximum number of actual installs (again a *test* box; spread over 3 drives).

Comment: I also have many installs. And first thing I do is turn off os-prober. It can take a while to scan for all the systems. I have some obsolete installs, that I would not boot anyway. I do put those installs I am testing into 40_custom so added to menu.

Answer (score 4):

From [the GRUB manual, in the *Features* section](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Features):

> There is no fixed limit on the number of boot entries, and the current implementation has space for several hundred.

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit for number of boot choices in GRUB boot loader. However, things get confusing and some hardware components may not behave as expected if more than two OS were installed.

For example, I'm having problems with Bluetooth headsets in dual boot of Windows and Linux. After some research I found that, different pairing keys are generated for the same device in Windows and Linux. So, we have to unpair and re-pair the device every time you login to other OS.

Comment: It's not addresses that are different, but pairing keys. I've used https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/255510/70524 reliably for multiple devices to fix this

Comment: Thank you for correction! And I'll check it out. :)